# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova App > how to add business layer?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am new to apache cordova mobile app development. I would like to build a cross platform mobile app. Here is what I did so far. (By the way, I am using **VS 2015**)

1. I implemented a windows forms app which uses Tesseract OCR.
2. I implemented an apache cordova mobile app which takes pictures, stores them and retrieves picture from image gallery.

Now I would like to use this tesseract OCR in my mobile app. (I would like to use this image which is taken by camera and send it to OCR) Apache Cordova projects consist only pure JS and HTML (CSS) so I wonder how can I use OCR as business layer of this mobile app? Actually I searched here and only came across this post: [Visual Studio 2015 Server side with Cordova Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116328/visual-studio-2015-server-side-with-cordova-apache)

Can I use the OCR source code in my mobile app? Or should I use web service calls? I really need your help.

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the source code in your mobile app, but you'll need to find a plugin that can do it for you. I just did some quick searching for "tesseract ocr cordova plugin" and found a number of promising GitHub projects. You'll need to see if any of these work for you or not. Add them to your project in Visual Studio using the custom tab and specifying the git URL.

If you can't find a workable plugin, then you either need to write one yourself or write a web service. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Michael Braude, thanks for your reply. How is it going to be if I want to use a web service? I mean can I move all the references and source code of OCR to mobile app?

Comment: Well presumably, you'd have to write a web service that can run the OCR code and expose an endpoint that takes an image and returns text. I'm not an expert on OCR or tesseract so I don't know how hard that could be.

Comment: Hello @Michael Braude, I implemented a WCF service which is hosted on my local IIS. Now I wonder if there is a way to debug this code? I mean is there a way to check, if clicking the button on the mobile app. triggers the WCF service?

Comment: Are you asking me how to set a breakpoint in a web service? Presumably that's all you have to do.